# How to retrieve unique identification from computer?

Tags: identifier, cpu-architecture

What can I  extract from computer to identify it.

MAC address,
Hard disk serial number,  then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a code to show you right now but i have done similar things, by cominning `CPU Id` and Harddrive serial No, that's how you get the unique no; 
try this; 
http://www.vcskicks.com/hardware_id.php

Comment: Oh yes CPU ID , thank You! When you judge another, you don't define them, you define yourself :).

Comment: don't use just cpuid, use it with harddrive only then you can be 100% sure that it is unique. And glad to help you :D